# Pip not installing

Tags: python, command-line, pip, command

I am trying to install pip but I am getting
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I ran get-pip.py and I tried adding the location where pip is installed to PATH in environment variables but it is still not working. I added it to both user and system variables.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I just needed to close and reopen the command prompt for the new directory to be recognized as added in PATH.